# Price Set with a conditional 'Other' field

Tags: civievent, price-sets

I have scanned the issue queue for any questions related to mine, and have come up empty, but apologies if there is another issue that I missed that would render this redundant!

I have a client organization that takes in money from event registrations. They would ideally like to have ~4-5 set pricing options as radio buttons for users to choose from, that would also include an 'Other' option which would allow the user to manually enter the amount they would prefer to contribute to the event, if not otherwise listed.

Now, while I know that this is certainly possible on Contribution pages, no such capability seems to exist within the Event page fee options, nor within Price Set options. Is there something that I am missing here, or is it really not possible to have an array of radio buttons to select a contribution amount for an event that includes an 'other' option?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an option in the event fees for 'Other' with a price value 0. Then create another price field with the type 'Text / Numeric Quantity' and a price of 1. Some other things you may want to consider with this method:

- Hide prices in the field setup and put them in the line item descriptions. This avoids the user seeing the $0 amount on the 'Other' option.
- In the 'Other' line item description you may want to add something like 'Enter amount below'
- With some simple jQuery you can hide the other amount field unless the 'Other' option is selected.

Hope this helps...